# Rest api with generic User

Tags: rest

I created a few Rest apis right now and I always preferred a solution, where I created an endpoint for each resource.

For example:

```
GET .../employees/{id}/account

GET .../supervisors/{id}/account
```

and the same with the other http methods like put, post and delete. This blows up my api pretty much. My rest apis in general preferred redundancy to reduce complexity but in this cases it always feels a bit cumbersome. So I create another approach where I work with inheritance to keep the "dry" principle.

In this case there is a base class User and via inheritance my employee and supervisor model extends from it. Now I only need one endpoint like

```
GET .../accounts/{id}
```

and the server decides which object is returned. Also while this thins out my api, it increases complexity and in my api documentation ( where I use spring rest docs ) I have to document two different Objects for the same endpoint.

Now I am not sure about what is the right way to do it ( or at least the better way ). When I think about Rest, I think in resources. So my employees are a seperate resource as well as my supervisors.
Because I always followed this approach, I tink I might be mentally run in it and maybe lost the objectivity.

It would be great if you can give my any objective advice on how this should be handled.

Comment: Why does having multiple endpoint 'blow' things up. Can't you re-use code between the similar endpoints? I personally think separate endpoints that share code is the ideal middleground. So what does 'blow up' mean, and if it means having to write a lot more code, is your framework preventing you from writing more general code?

Comment: With blow up I mean that there are much more endpoints

Comment: Why does that matter for your application? Can you try to explain the negative side-effects you perceive of having more routes.

Answer (score 0):

I built an online service that deals with this too. It's called Wirespec:

https://wirespec.dev

The backend automatically creates the url for users and their endpoints dynamically with very little code. The code for handling the frontend is written in Kotlin while the backend for generating APIs for users is written in Node.js. In both cases, the amount of code is very negligible and self-maintaining, meaning that if the user changes the name of their API, the endpoint automatically updates with the name. Here are some examples:

API: https://wirespec.dev/Wirespec/projects/apis/Stackoverflow/apis/getUserDetails

Endpoint: https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/getuserdetails?id=100

So to answer your question, it really doesn't matter where you place the username in the url.

Try signing in to Wirespec with your Github account and you'll see where your Github username appears in the url.

Answer (score 0):

There is, unfortunately, no wright or wrong answer to this one and it soley depends on how you want to design things.

With that being said, you need to distinguish between client and server. A client shouldn't know the nifty details of your API. It is just an arbitrary consumer of your API that is fed all the information it needs in order to make informed choices. I.e. if you want the client to send some data to the server that follows a certain structure, the best advice is to use from-like representations, such as [HAL forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [Ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms) or even [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html). Forms not only teach a client about the respective properties a resource supports but also about the HTTP operation to use, the target URI to send the request to as well as the representation format to send the data in, which in case of HTML is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` most of the time.

In regards to receiving data from the server, a client shouldn't attempt to extract knowledge from URIs directly, as they may change over time and thus break clients that rely on such a methodology, but rely on link relation names. Per URI there might be multiple link relation names attached to that URI. A client not knowing the meaning of one should simply ignore it. Here, either one of the standardized [link relation names](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) should be used or an extension mechanism as defined by [Web linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2). While an arbitrary client might not make sense from this "arbitrary string" out of the box, the link relation name may be considered the predicate in a tripple often used in ontologies where the link relation name "connects" the current resource with the one the link relation was annotated for. For a set of URIs and link relation names you might therefore "learn" a semantic graph over all the resources and how they are connected to each other. I.e. you might annotate an URI pointing to a form resource with `prefetch` to hint a client that it may load the content of the referenced URI if it is IDLE as the likelihood is high that the client will be interested to load that resource next anyway. The same URI might also be annotated with `edit-form` to hint a client that the resource will provide an edit form to send some data to the server. It might also contain a Web linking extension such as `https://acme.org/ref/orderForm` that allows clients, that support such a custom extension, to react to such a resource accordingly.

In your accounts example, it is totally fine to return different data for different resources of the same URI-path. I.e. resource A pointing to an employee account might only contain properties name, age, position, salery while resource B pointing to a supervisor could also contain a list of subordinates or the like. To a generic HTTP client these are two totally different resources even though they used a URI structure like `/accounts/{id}`. Resources in a REST architecture are [untyped](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html), meaning they don't have a type ouf of the box per se. Think of some arbitrary Web page you access through your browser. Your browser is not aware of whether the Web page it renders contains details about a specific car or about the most recent local news. HTML is designed to express a multitude of different data in the same way. Different media types though may provide more concrete hints about the data exchanged. I.e. `text/vcard`, `applciation/vcard+xml` or `application/vcard+json` all may respresent data describing an entity (i.e. human person, jusistic entity, animal, ...) while `application/mathml+xml` might be used to express certain mathematical formulas and so on. The more general a media type is, the more wiedspread usage it may find. With more narrow media types however you can provide more specific support. With content type negotiation you also have a tool at your hand where a client can express its capabilities to servers and if the server/API is smart enough it can respond with a representation the client is able to handle.

This in essence is all what REST is and if followed correctly allow the decoupling of clients from specific servers. While this might sound confusing and burdensome to implement at first, these techniques are intended if you strive for a long-lasting environment that still is able to operate in decateds to come. Evolution is inherently integrated into this phiolosophy and supported by the decoupled design. If you don't need all of that, REST might not be the thing you want to do actually. Buf if you still want something like REST, you for sure should design the interactions between client and server as if you'd intereact with a typical Web server. After all, REST is just a generalization of the concepts used on the Web quite successfully for the past two decades.